# How to change mysql database directory on WAMP

Tags: mysql, windows, wamp

I'm running a dual boot server with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. On Ubuntu, everything is configured how I want it. On Windows, I need to know how to change my MySQL database directory so that it uses the same directory I'm using on Ubuntu. How do I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hope this image would guide clear. You can write click and select view image to see my answer clearly

[image]

**Please don't forget to restart wamp/xampp after these steps then it will be applied**

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for taking the time to illustrate it.

Comment: If your doing this to recover an old database you'll want to also check out https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/innodb-ignoring-the-redo-log-due-to-missing-mlog-checkpoint?rq=1&newreg=c1f5dadd1cb44bc7927b2c1213b40ba0 Just make sure you disable recovery after your done!

Comment: I have followed these tips but got an error: Failed to find a valid data directory. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your given path is not valid or accessible or a typing mistake in path.

@arhakim sorry its late, but answer to your issue could not be confirmed without knowing your directory structure and persmissions.

Answer (score 7):

[1](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) in [WAMP sever 2.2](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) [ in windows ],

go to **C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\my.ini**

[2] you will find like this,

**datadir=*c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/data***

[3] change this with

" **datadir = *Your Ubuntu MySql Data Directory Path*** ".

[4] **Then restart wamp serever**.

i hope this will helpful to solve your problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If your doing this to recover an old database you'll want to also check out https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/innodb-ignoring-the-redo-log-due-to-missing-mlog-checkpoint?rq=1&newreg=c1f5dadd1cb44bc7927b2c1213b40ba0 Just make sure you disable recovery after your done!

Answer (score -2):

i Have better idea ...
open phpmyadmin page ... and select you data base ... on the operations tab and in the Rename database to section ... write your new Database name . 
you will see tow message . press yes button for both

Comment: He wasn't asking how to change the database name, he's asking how to re configure the Data folder location.