# Change of MySQL database location not working

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Updating from WampServer 2.2 and Windows 7 to WampServer 2.5 and Windows 10. I change database and document locations with

```
basedir=D:/Progs/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17
log-error=D:/Progs/wamp/logs/mysql.log
#datadir=D:/Progs/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data
datadir=D:\Documents\MySQLdata
```

in D:\Progs\wamp\bin\mysql5.6.17\my.ini, and

```
#DocumentRoot "D:/Progs/wamp/www/"
DocumentRoot "D:/Documents/WWW/"
...
#<Directory "D:/Progs/wamp/www/">
<Directory "D:/Documents/WWW/">
```

in D:\Progs\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf.

phpMyAdmin however still points to D:\Progs\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data and new databases are made there. I am certain that the changes above worked ok in previous reinstalls of the old version in Windows 7.

Comment: apache and mysql restarted?

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin doesn't go with the path for dealing with the database. Instead it connects to mysql itself with the configuration for that in the file `config.inc.php`.

Change this in your `my.ini`:

```
# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
```

To this:

```
# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld64]
```

Restart and that should do the trick.

[This was found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155243/changing-the-datadir-on-my-ini-file-is-not-being-respected-in-wamp)

---

*Did not work here:*

Since you are on Windows, look into the folder 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6' (or similar) and change the my.ini there.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I have no folder "C:\ProgramData\MySQL..." and in fact I can find no other my.ini file at all.

Comment: Do you see anything in wampmanager.conf or config.inc? One more thing you can try is changing your PATH. How do you see that it points to the wrong path?

Comment: Nothing that looks relevant in those two files. I say that phpMyAdmin points to "D:\Progs\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data" because, if I make a new database, that is where it ends up.

Comment: Thank you again, but unfortunately that also did not help; nor did removing the 64 bit version, and replacing it with the 32 bit version (I don't remember which version I had previously)

Comment: For the moment I have gven up, and moved my database to where phpMyAdmin expects to find it (although I prefer having it in my Documents folder for backup reasons).