# Change WAMP MySQL Data Location not working

Tags: mysql, location

I am running WAMP off of a Google Drive folder, which is working fine on my home computer. But when I try to access it from my work computer that I have synced with Google Drive, I run into problems. I'm trying to change the MySQL Data location to the location on the Google Drive folder. I looked at the solution on these pages:

[How to change mysql database directory on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657081/how-to-change-mysql-database-directory-on-wamp)

[Change of MySQL database location not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121701/change-of-mysql-database-location-not-working)

But it didn't do the trick. MySQL is still looking at the data location on my work computer and not at the one on the Google Drive folder.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default WAMP Server is not meant to be a portable application.

But a portable application is what you want.

I'd check out the following portable WAMP solutions:

http://www.uniformserver.com/

http://www.uwamp.com/en/

http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/

They will better suit your needs!

I'd install one to the Google Drive and transfer all your projects to it.

Then you will never ever have to worry about something like this coming up.

Comment: Which one of those would you say is the best?

Comment: That is a highly opinion based question. But I'd have to go with uwamp personally. Feel free to check each site and make your own choice.

Comment: If you feel this answers your question please remember to mark my answer as correct.