# change root folder of the mysql database for wamp

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp

I am aware that `www` is the root folder for the WAMP all sites content and its changeable.

How about wamp's folder for all its existing databases? Can we redirect its location as well? Are they even exist?
I tried to google it and surprising find no result of the folder location for databases in MySQL or wamp,

What I searched:
[change root folder of the mysql database for wamp](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS549US549&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=change%20root%20folder%20of%20the%20mysql%20database%20for%20wamp)

Comment: [How to change mysql database directory on WAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657081/how-to-change-mysql-database-directory-on-wamp)

Comment: @kums Ah! So there is one data folder for all the databases! cool! btw, can all the data folder content just be copy and pasted into a new version of wamp installed in other machine? Thanks!

Comment: Yes! Don't just copy... Move the entire data folder to the new location.

Comment: RE:Copying folder. Make sure you copy the whole `\data\` folder but after you have stopped MySQL so it has closed and cleaned up all databases. Also make sure MySQL is stopped on the new Machine before copying. Otherwise you may get issues bringing MySQL up on the second machine.  Also the version of MySQL that is being used on both machines in the copy should be that same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WAMPServer puts all databases in `wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.x` if they are INNODB databases and `wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.x\data` for MYISAM databases and some parts of the INNODB databases.

MySQL is controlled by a file called `my.ini` or `my.cnf` but WAMPServer uses the `my.ini` file which is found by using the wampmanager menu system

```
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> my.ini
```

or manually editing the file `wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.x\my.ini`. Stick to using the wampmanager menus.

The location of the databases is controlled by a parameter called `datadir` example `datadir=d:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data`

One word of warning, if you are using the WAMPServer 2.5 64bit version there is a minor bug in this file. The section header [wampmysqld] shoudl be chnaged to [wampmysqld64]
**But only if you are using the 64bit version of WAMPServer.

While you are in the `my.ini` file it is also a good idea to change this parameter which controls the language that error messages are shown in

```
lc-messages=fr_FR
```

to your prefered language Eg

```
lc-messages=en_GB
```