# MYSQL/Databases Databases gone?

Tags: mysql

I have been working on my first project using databases using MySQL. I woke up this morning unable to login to localhost. I am able to enter root with no password and none of my databases are there. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean unable to login? Your credentials are not accepted?

Comment: yes It says acess denied and when i tried to login without a password it works but no databases are present

Comment: Which MySQL Version, which OS, and which client ?

Comment: windows 10 mysql 5.7.7 using Wamp and workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory root should have access to all your databases. If you haven't deleted them, it's possible you just lost access to them. Remember that MySQL is host-sensitive when logging in.

`root@%`,`root@localhost`, `root@10.0.0.1`, etc... all may be assigned different permissions.

You can try `skip-grant-table` in `my.ini`, as explained in this answer:

[Regaining access to lost MySQL password for PHPMyAdmin on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070501/regaining-access-to-lost-mysql-password-for-phpmyadmin-on-wamp)

With this you can reset the root password and try again.

If this does not yield effect, I would look into your SQL history and see if you haven't accidentally deleted them?

Comment: I didint  delete anything but how is it possible my passsword just stopped working

Comment: Ok so I checked mydata folder and they are still there which is a sigh of releif I think

Comment: Just need to reset your root password, and you should be able to get to them. In general, you'd want to create a new MySQL user that is specific to your application, so that you are not using `root` in production.
You can do this by using:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Comment: Once you manage to reset the root password, please accept the provided answer in the system as correct. Thanks and good luck :)

Comment: Im following the post exactly however it requests a password from me when  I open mysql console but accepts no password is this normal?

Comment: Did you stop the Wamp MySQL service, then edited `my.ini`, and then started again?

If you correctly set skip-grant-tables as explained in the article, you should have no password prompt.  Perhaps you edited without restarted the MySQL service?

Comment: So I reset the password but its still not showing mydatabases that are in mydata folder

Comment: Are you root? check that the data directory matches your configuration.

If you are root, you should be able to create a new user using create and grant as in the 2nd article.

Comment: Yes i stopped edited restarted and it doesnt work :(

Comment: How do i check  that the data directory matches my configuration?

Comment: `datadir` setting in `my.ini`: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657081/how-to-change-mysql-database-directory-on-wamp

Comment: what happens when you try to create a new user? are you allowed to do so? can you use the GRANT permissions operation as linked above?

Comment: I changed the directory and I now seem to have access to my databases and my password is the same as before I dont know what  happend and how it changed but thank you.

Comment: Seriously thanks alot I have like 5 projects I was working on and thought it was all gone because before I didint udnerstand where databases files were even stored